# Gzip Compression not working

Tags: .htaccess, compression, gzip, yslow

I have a website in which Yslow saying You need to Compress the Components with gzip.

So i have found the below information in my apache response when i echo phpinfo() as my test.php file.

---

SERVER_SOFTWARE                   Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) PHP/5.3.5 
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING                  gzip, deflate 
Accept-Encoding                   gzip, deflate 
gzip compression                  enabled

### _SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]       gzip, deflate

And then i followed this tutorial and copied and pasted the below code to my .htaccess file.

---

```
<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_keep_workfiles No
mod_gzip_can_negotiate Yes
mod_gzip_add_header_count Yes
mod_gzip_send_vary Yes
mod_gzip_command_version '/mod_gzip_status'
mod_gzip_min_http 1000
mod_gzip_minimum_file_size 300
mod_gzip_maximum_file_size 512000
mod_gzip_maximum_inmem_size 60000
mod_gzip_handle_methods GET POST
mod_gzip_temp_dir /tmp
mod_gzip_item_include file \.html$
mod_gzip_item_include file \.php$
mod_gzip_item_include file \.pl$
mod_gzip_item_include file \.rb$
mod_gzip_item_include file \.py$
mod_gzip_item_include file \.cgi$
mod_gzip_item_include file \.css$
mod_gzip_item_include file \.js$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/javascript$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^httpd/unix-directory$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^server-status$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^server-info$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^application/x-httpd-php
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
</IfModule>
```

---

but it does not make any difference as i m still getting the file compression error as YSlow recommends .

I have also tried some other scripts by referring some other pages tutorials without any success.

Please can anybody give me solution how to solve this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/css text/html text/xml
</IfModule>
```

Also, clear your browser's cache and restart the browser to ensure it's not caching the non-gzip'd response.

Comment: True, but it should still satisfy Yslow's compression requirements. GZIP is based on the DEFLATE algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

Some servers may not have the apache modules (gzip, deflate) installed.  One way around this is to add the following to your .htaccess:

```
php_flag zlib.output_compression On
php_value zlib.output_compression_level 5
```

Comment: after adding this site giving 500